# Is there a way to configure Big Query and slack to post a message on success of a scheduled query?

Tags: google-bigquery, slack

I have many scheduled queries running on a project and it is getting hard to keep track of which script or query is breaking. Is there a way that I can add send a slack notification after each scheduled query runs successfully?

This would hopefully let me go through the logs on slack each morning to see which query broke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging) and [Notification Channel](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options) to achieve your goal.

In a nutshell what we gonna do is that we will setup logs-based alert policy which will notify Slack channel (configured via Notification Channel).

---

First, please create a channel connected with Slack - steps can be [found here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#slack).

Now let's focus on BigQuery. Please go to the "Schedules Queries" page in BigQuery and select (click)  any query.

[image]

Please click again on the query details to get more information.

[image]

"Run details" box will appear on the right side of the screen. Please click the "View in Logs explorer" button.

[image]

Now, we are in the Logs Explorer. Please click the "Create alert" button.

[image]

Please provide an alert name, and click "Next".

[image]

In the second step of creating logs-based alert policy ("Choose logs to include in the alert") you need to create an inclusion filter (more [information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813103/where-is-the-documentation-for-google-cloud-loggings-inclusion-exclusion-filter)), for example (to catch logs from all BigQuery scheduled queries):

```
resource.type=bigquery_dts_config severity>=DEFAULT
```

You can use the "Preview Logs" option to check which logs will be captured.

[image]

In the third step, please set notification frequency and autoclose duration to the values you want.

In the last, fourth step please choose your notification channel connected with Slack that you created at the beginning.

[image]

Please click save.

Voila! From now you will get notifications about BigQuery queries in your Slack channel.